# Regex: Extracting img-tags from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make this:

```
<span class="introduction">
   <img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />
</span>
```

transform into this:

```
   <img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />
```

How would I do this with regex? That is, how do I extract ONLY the img-tag from a given string of html?

Note: There can be a lot more html within the introduction-tag BUT only one img-tag

Comment: Oh man...Prepare to be downvoted.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [Use a proper html / xml parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Don't use regex.

Comment: img tags can't be nested (as far as I someone with almost no html experience). Therefore they are regular (IIRC).
Thus Regex can solve the problem. 
However a html parser may be easier

Comment: @fireeyedboy: People sometimes do that, if they get a reference answer, not dated joke links.

Comment: @Oxinabox PCRE can parse non-regular languages.

Comment: Then my statement holds. It can parse out the image tags.
I don't see why this question alwaysg ets down voted. The Question is reasonable (Though similar has been asked before), Answers that say Regex is the best way to do this, are what should be downvoted, (Though I am over generalising here).

Comment: Use this... <img[^>]*>(.*?)(?:</img>)? with caution...

Comment: @Oxinabox they get dv'ed exactly for the reason you state. They have been asked and answered a gazillion times before. There was obviously no research effort invested into this and that's a dv reason according to the tooltip you get when putting your mouse over the dv button. Also, its kinda ridiculous that its basically a duplicate of any question involving getElementsByTagName but the Regex fanatics insist on providing patterns for it until each and every possible pattern combination has been given.

Comment: Fair enough, so long as we aren't downvoting for what is simply a new man's mistake. (Of thinking regex is a suitable solution,(I think alot of us have been down that path when we first wanted to scrape some data))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't really use regex on HTML, what about this:?

```
$string = '<span class="introduction"><img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" /></span>';

echo strip_tags($string, '<img>');
```

Otherwise I would use an HTML/XML parser

Comment: You need the brackets in the allowable tags `echo strip_tags($string, '<img>');` - but yeah - that would work.

Comment: if `$string = '<span class="introduction"><img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />some text here</span>';` then it gets `<img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />some text here` which is not the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
"<img[^>]*>"
```

try with grep

```
kent$  echo '<span class="introduction">
quote>    <img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />
quote> </span>
quote> '|grep -P "<img[^>]*>"
   <img alt="image" src="/picture.jpg" />
```

Comment: This would fail if they typed `<img alt=">" src="/path.jpg" />`

Comment: ... and just hope nobody manages to create an image called "my>image.jpg"; you **can't** do it on Windows - even via `ren` in a DOS prompt - dunno about anything else though :)

Comment: I need this. but i want to keep style attributes

Answer (score 5):

`preg_match('#(<img.*?>)#', $string, $results);`

should work, result in `$results[1]`

Comment: how to keep style attributes for img tag

Answer (score 1):

[Use DOM and this XPath:](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

```
//span[@class="introduction"]/img
```

to find all img elements that are direct children of any span element with a class attribute of introduction.

Answer (score 1):

I've come to this solution

`/<img ([^>"']*("[^"]*"|'[^']*')?[^>"']*)*>/`

tested on

`<other html elements like span or whatever><img src="asd>qwe" attr1='asd>qwe' attr2='as"dqwe' attr3="as'dqwe" ></other html elements like span or whatever>`