# preg_replace and preg_match_all to move img from wordpress $content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am using `preg_replace` to delete from `$content` certain `<img>`:

```
$content=preg_replace('/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/','',$content);
```

When I am now displaying the content using wordpress the_content function, I did indeed remove the `<img>`s from `$content`:

I'd like beforehand to get this images to place them elsewhere in the template. I am using the same regex pattern with `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/', $content, $matches);
```

But I can't get my imgs?

```
preg_match_all('/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/', $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end i have used preg_replace_callback:

```
$content2 = get_the_content();                    
$removed_imgs = array();                 
$content2 = preg_replace_callback('#(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)(<img.+? />)#',function($r) {
                    global $removed_imgs;
                    $removed_imgs[] = $r[1];
                    return '';
                },$content2);


 foreach($removed_imgs as $img){
                echo $img;
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming and hopefully you are using php5, this is a task for DOMDocument and xpath. regex with html elements mostly will work, but check the following example [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821387/regex-extracting-img-tags-from-string)

```
<img alt=">" src="/path.jpg" />
```

regex will fail. since there aren't many guarantees in programming, take the guarantee that xpath will find EXACTLY what you want, at a perfomance cost, so to code it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<span><img src="com.png" /><img src="com2.png" /></span>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//span/img');
$html = '';
foreach($imgs as $img){
  $html .= $doc->saveXML($img);
}
```

now you have all img elements in `$html`, use `str_replace()` to remove them from `$content`, and from there you can have a drink and be pleased that xpath with html elements is painless, just a little slower

ps. i couldnt be be bother understanding your regex, i just think xpath is better in your situation

Comment: thanks ! that looks great ! i have solved my problem but keep this in mind for next time